# Как обеспечить обмен данных клиента с сервером

Tags: json, клиент-сервер

Как обеспечить обмен данных клиента с сервером. Мобильное приложение делает запрос на сервер и получает данные в json формате. Запрос - простая ссылкая типа host/pharmacy/34. По сути сейчас кто угодно может отправлять запрос серверу. Как запретить отправляться запрос на сервер всем, кроме приложения. Или хотя бы подскажите в какую сторону гуглить?

Comment: Никак, в вашей компетенции только не отдавать данные кому попало. Если сервер торчит наружу - может прийти кто угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно разрешить доступ к файлам каталога только UserAgent Вашего приложения приложения. Это не панацея, т.к. существуют способы его подделать. Но простой пользователь не сможет из браузера выполнить скрипт или получить доступ к файлам.

Чтобы это осуществить, нужно задать UserAgent приложению, например, как это указано здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent

Также нужно прописать разрешение только одному UserAgent в файле .htaccess, который нужно поместить в каталоге, доступ к файлам которого нужно запретить. Например для UserAgent My Android App файл будет такой:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !My\sAndroid\sApp [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Пробелы заменяются на \s.